# Can't upload user picked image to firebase storage and download url to store in database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a picture picked by the user to firebase storage and then the url downloaded so the picture can be stored in realtime database, but have not been able to get it working with my code! I was originally going to use metadata!.downloadUrl() but that is no longer functional because of an update, so I am lost.

Here is my code:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class createPostViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var contactEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactPhoneNum: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var gender: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastSeen: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileDescription: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var postBtn: UIButton!
    
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var selectedImage: UIImage!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(createPostViewController.handleSelect))
        profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        postBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    

    @objc func handleSelect(){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func post(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("profiles").child(userID!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
               // "userImg":  as AnyObject,
                "name": self.name.text as AnyObject,
                "contactEmail": self.contactEmail.text as AnyObject,
                "contactPhoneNum": self.contactPhoneNum.text as AnyObject,
                "age": self.age.text as AnyObject,
                "gender": self.gender.text as AnyObject,
                "lastSeen": self.lastSeen.text as AnyObject,
                "profileDescription": self.profileDescription.text as AnyObject,
            ]
            
            let firebasePost = Database.database().reference().child("profiles").childByAutoId()
            firebasePost.setValue(post)
        })
        
    }
    
    
    
    func uploadImageToFireBase(image: UIImage) {
        // Create the file metadata
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let profileRef = storageRef.child("images/rivers.jpg")
        // Upload the file to the path FILE_NAME
        Storage.storage().reference().child("FILE_NAME").putData(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.42)!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            guard let metadata = metadata else {
              // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
              print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
              return
            }
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
            let size = metadata.size
            
            print("Upload size is \(size)")
            print("Upload success")
        }
    }
    

    
    
    //func uploadToCloud(fileURL : URL) {
      //  let storage = Storage.storage()
        
        //let data = Data()
        
        //let storageRef = storage.reference()
        
        //let localFule = fileURL
        
        //let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        //let photoRef = storageRef.child("profilePhoto\(userID)")
        
        //let uploadTask = photoRef.putFile(from: localFule, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
          //  guard let metadata = metadata else {
            //    print(err?.localizedDescription)
              //  return
            //}
            //print("Photo Upload")
            
       // }
   // }
}

extension createPostViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
      func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image =  info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = image
             print("success")
              profileImage.image = image
              uploadImageToFireBase(image: selectedImage)
          } else {
              print("image wasnt selected")
          }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that attempts to store the url in the Firebase Realtime Database, and you would not get that from the metadata. Additionally, get the download url from the file reference you create to store it (e.g. `let riversRef = storageRef.child("images/rivers.jpg")` but there's not one of those either. Take a look at the Getting Started Guide [Upload from data in Memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory) as it shows the code to do that. Then update your question with your actual code and indicate where it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still use the `downloadUrl` method on the storage reference.

```
func uploadImageToFireBase(image: UIImage) {
    // Create the file metadata
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    
    // Upload the file to the path FILE_NAME
    Storage.storage().reference().child("FILE_NAME").putData(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.42)!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            print((error?.localizedDescription))
            return
        }
        
        Storage.storage().reference().child("FILE_NAME").downloadURL { (imageUrl, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                let currentUserRef = Database.database().reference().child("profiles").child(userID)
                currentUserRef.updateChildValues(["profileImage": imageUrl])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pls see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63424875/5443937) answer.

Comment: I have tried this but the image still doesn't seem to be uploading

Comment: Is th uploaded image not appearing under `storage` in firebase console. Pls check if you have `read, write` permissions in the storage

Comment: I have used breakpoints and I don't think the function is calling

Comment: Which function is not getting called?

Comment: uploadImageToFirebase, as I put a breakpoint at the function and it has not been reached.

Comment: are you getting the selected image in `imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method? Try removing `rawValue` from `if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage.rawValue] as? UIImage`

Comment: DId it work? It will not give you the edited image from image picker. Use `info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage]`

Comment: It returns the error: Cannot convert value of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: did you use `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey. editedImage` ?

Comment: yes I did: if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage]as? UIImage

Comment: didn't that work? Else use `info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]`

Comment: I changed the line to that and also added a print function and breakpoint: if let image =  info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]as? UIImage {
              selectedImage = image
             print("success") - however neither of these are appearing so I don't think the func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) is running

Comment: You have setup an `imagePicker` in `viewDidLoad` with `allowsEditing = true`, but using a new `pickerController` inside your tap gesture function. Either use `imagePicker` in `handleSelect()` function or set `allowsEditing = true` for `pickerController` created in that function.

Comment: I have changed that, please see the updated code. The post information is now being uploaded but the image is not, and this error is showing: 
[GatekeeperXPC] Connection to assetsd was interrupted - assetsd exited, died, or closed the photo library

Comment: why are you again calling `uploadImageToFireBase(image: selectedImage)` inside `uploadImageToFireBase` method?

Comment: I have updated my code above, however am getting the following error: 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value' at line 47: 'uploadImageToFireBase(image: selectedImage)'. But I am not force unwrapping any value?

Comment: `selectedImage` is an implicitly unwrapped optional. Check `post` method, you are trying to upload the image even before there is a selected image. check if selectedImage is nil before uploading

Comment: I have called the **uploadImageToFireBase(image: selectedImage)** in the **imagePickerController** function, however the breakpoint I placed there is not being reached

Comment: I've already asked you to set  'allowsEditing = true` for image picker